# dodge points and errorbars by multiple variables ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that I'm plotting with a value and a 95% CI. I have four grouping variables, and for some unchangeable reasons, I would like to facet the plot only by one variable.

```r
var1 = as.factor(c("x", "y", "z"))
var2 = as.factor(c("a", "b", "c"))
var3 = as.factor(c("one", "two", "three"))
var4 = as.factor(c("lorem", "ipsum"))

df <- expand.grid(var1, var2, var3, var4) 
names(df) <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")

df$mean <- sample(seq(-10, 10, 0.1), nrow(df), replace = FALSE)
df$stderr <- sample(seq(1, 5, 0.01), nrow(df), replace = FALSE)

df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    up = mean + (1.96 * stderr),
    lo = mean - (1.96 * stderr)
  )

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = var1, ymin = lo, ymax = up,
                    group = var3), 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
                width = 0) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = var1, y = mean, fill = var3, group = var3,
                 shape = var4),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 3) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green")) + 
  facet_wrap(~var2) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The plot looks almost exactly how I want it, as I can use `position_dodge()` to group points with each other by one variable (i.e. the fill variable in this case). My challenge is that *within* each fill colour, I want to be able to `position_dodge()` again by the shape so the errorbars and points are not on exactly the same place in the x-axis, and therefore, are not overlapping on top of one other. That is, for example in the first two set of points on the far left, the blue square and blue circle are on exactly the same x-axis point so the errorbars overlap exactly, but I would like to be able to dodge them to just beside each other, so there are **two** dodge values, `var3` *and* `var4`.

I can't figure out how to do this, does anyone know if you can either do this with the `group =`  argument or some other way? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So in all my digging I found that `group` can't accept more than one argument, so to achieve my desired end point, I found a passable answer utilizing @teunbrand 's cool function `facet_nested` from the `ggh4x` package, and their subsequent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73462658/how-to-remove-nesting-facet-labels-in-facet-nested-ggh4x-package). Ideally I would have the points grouped with each of the colours for each x-axis label beside each other but this definitely works!

```
strips <- strip_nested(
  text_x = list(element_text(), element_blank()),
  background_x = list(element_blank(), element_blank()), 
  by_layer_x = TRUE
)

ggplot(data = df, aes(fill = var3, group = var3, shape = var4)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = var1, ymin = lo, ymax = up), 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),
                width = 0) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = var1, y = mean),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), size = 3) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green")) + 
  ggh4x::facet_nested(~var2+var4,
                      strip = strips) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]